# Android widget: download and parse JSON and write it to TextView on user click

Tags: android, json, widget

I am writing simple widget that parse and show content of JSON.

Widget have only one TextView in layout. I do not want automatic update. Widget will update TextView after user click on this text.

I am starting with Android programming. It is my first app.

Now I have this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppWidgetProvider {

    String temperature;

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

        for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
            int currentWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            String url = "http://example.net/json.php";

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));

            PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    intent, 0);
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.activity_main);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.textView1, pending);

            /*
            try {
                String a = "{  \"temperature\": 4.3\" }";
                JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(a);
                String x = reader.getString("temperature");
                Log.i("temperature", x);
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, x);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             */

            fetchJSON(url);

            views.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, temperature+new Date().getSeconds());

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(currentWidgetId, views);
            Toast.makeText(context, "widget added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    public void fetchJSON(final String url) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    URL u = new URL(url);
                    HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) u
                            .openConnection();
                    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlConn;
                    httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                    httpConn.connect();
                    InputStream in = httpConn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);
                    ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(1000);
                    int read = 0;
                    int bufSize = 1024;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufSize];
                    while (true) {
                        read = bis.read(buffer);
                        if (read == -1) {
                            break;
                        }
                        baf.append(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                    String queryResult = new String(baf.toByteArray());

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(queryResult);

                    temperature = jsonObject.getString("temperature");
                    Log.i("TEMP", temperature);

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        thread.start();
    }

}
```

If I uncomment section with JSON in String it write string to TextView on widget - OK.

After I run app in emulator I see "null3". 3 is seconds. If I click on widget, android open browser window but do not update widget text. I still see "null3". In console I see "TEMP" entry with right value.

It is possible only update text of widget and do not open web browser?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `Thread` did not run yet when you set the text in the `TextView`. You have to wait for that. Look at [Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), that is especially made for task like yours. You can update the text in `onPostExecute()`